# How do I change the database being updated with Update-Database in Visual Studio's Package Manager?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am using Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 8. I have a test db and website that I've been working on for the past month. I am using Azure as the host. I am using ASP.Net MVC Core 3.1 with Entity Framework. I am ready to port everything over to the live site. However, I can't figure out how to tell Update-Database to target the live db. Every time I run it, it tries to update the test db. I thought I would just have to change the connection string being referenced in Startup.ConfigureServices(..).

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
        new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<MapItGO_DbContext>(opts => {
            opts.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MapItGODBConnection"]); //"ConnectionStrings:MapItGODBConnection/MapItGOTestDBConnection"
        });
```

I have multiple ConnectionStrings defined in appsettings.json:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MapItGoDBConnection": "Server=tcp:mapitgo.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mapitgodb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
    "MapItGOTestDBConnection": "Server=tcp:mapitgo.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mapitgotestdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
    "MapItGo_Web_AppContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MapItGo Web App;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

I'm losing whatever hair I've got left at this point. What should have been a quick and easy go-live has consumed the better part of a day now. I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks!

Edit:

```
PM> update-database -verbose
Using project 'MapItGo Web App'.
Using startup project 'MapItGo Web App'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile "C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MapItGo Web App.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\gregoryshill\.nuget\packages --runtimeconfig "C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MapItGo Web App.runtimeconfig.json" C:\Users\gregoryshill\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.14\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll database update --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly "C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MapItGo Web App.dll" --startup-assembly "C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MapItGo Web App.dll" --project-dir "C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\\" --language C# --working-dir "C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App" --root-namespace MapItGo_Web_App
Using assembly 'MapItGo Web App'.
Using startup assembly 'MapItGo Web App'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App'.
Using root namespace 'MapItGo_Web_App'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\gregoryshill\source\repos\MapItGo Web App\MapItGo Web App\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'MapItGO_DbContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'MapItGO_DbContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'MapItGo Web App'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'MapItGo Web App'...
No design-time services were found.
Done.
```

And, no, I haven't overridden OnConfiguring. What belongs there?

Update:

This is in appsettings.Development.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

That's it.

**Update (2021-06-28)**: I figured it out. See my final comment below. It was buried in the secrets.json file.

Comment: Run the update command with `--verbose` flag: `dotnet ef database update --verbose`, and add the logs here.

Comment: Also, did you override `OnConfiguring` method of the DbContext?

Comment: Do you have other `appsettings.$env.json` files with `ConnectionStrings` section defined? They might be overriding what you've posted here.

Comment: Ok, rewind. Does it work at all if you hardcode the connection string inside `UseSqlServer` method?

Comment: If not, check out configuration debug view to see where the actual values come from: https://andrewlock.net/debugging-configuration-values-in-aspnetcore/

Comment: I've added GetDebugView() to Startup.Configure(..), but I'm getting no results. I have a breakpoint set inside of the call, but it never triggers.

Comment: It gives you a string. You can view it inside the debugger or print it out to console with `Debug.WriteLine()`

Comment: It never executes the lambda expression inside of endpoints.MapGet(...).

Comment: if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                    endpoints.MapGet("/debug-config", ctx => {
                        var config = (Configuration as IConfigurationRoot).GetDebugView();

                        Debug.WriteLine(config);

                        return ctx.Response.WriteAsync(config);
                    });
                }

Comment: Does `env.IsDevelopment()` evaluate to `true`? Having the wrong environment would explain a lot here

Comment: When you deploy, `Environment` is most likely set to `Production` which reads only `appsettings.json` (and not `appsettings.Development.json`) so your connection string configuration would be moot. Because as you posted, there's nothing (worthwhile) configured inside `appsettings.json` i.e. `Production` configuration.

Comment: Also, remove the `if (env.IsDevelopment())` check, check out what comes out first before locking it down to Development environment.

Comment: I've commented out the IsDev condition. It simply never gets to the lambda expression. I also copied the contents of appsettings.Development.json to appsettings.json. Still no glory

Comment: Thanks for your help, by the way. I really appreciate the time you're putting into this.

Comment: There's some spooky stuff going on. You know what, I'm gonna help you out with this. Reach me out at the email in my profile.

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently secrets.json is not searchable when searching the solution in VS 2019. I went into Connected Services, rebuilt the secrets file, loaded it manually, and sure enough, I had a reference to the test db in there. I changed it to the live db, and everything worked perfectly. Thank you @abdusco for firing questions and potential solutions at me. You kept me digging. I appreciate it.

Comment: I was just writing a reply to you. I'd never user used dotnet secrets feature before, so that would have never come to my mind. Glad you sorted it out :)

Comment: I'll summarize what we tried and post and answer, hopefully someone else won't waste as much time as you did

Comment: It still boggles me how it doesn't work with hardcoded connection string. That's not how computers supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to happen, the app must be reading the invalid connection string from somewhere, somehow.
You need to scrub every bit of your app from the test connection string. This includes:

1. `appsettings.json`, and `appsettings.$env.json`
2. Environment variables. Restart the console/IDE you're running the app and make sure you haven't set `ConnectionStrings__$MyConnectionString`
3. If you're using [dotnet secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows), make sure you don't have anything wrong in there. Run `dotnet user-secrets list` to check it.
4. Commandline arguments. Check out your IDE's launch settings, you might have set and forgot something there.
5. Check any custom configuration provider (Azure Key Vault, Hashicorp Vault etc.) from which your app reads configuration.
6. Any runtime configuration.

Alternatively, check [`IConfiguration.GetDebugView()`](https://andrewlock.net/debugging-configuration-values-in-aspnetcore/) and see where each configuration comes from.

Once you find it, change the connection string to the real one.